# Fixing the thumb lever of a Shimano Rapidfire SL-M4100-R - doesn't retract if shift >1 cog

Tags: repair, shifter

New bike with a SL-M4100-R deore rapidfire shifter, with shift indicator, 10 speed. Shifts fine both ways 1 gear at a time. However, using the thumb lever (moving from smaller to bigger cogs, harder to easier gears) and doing 2 or 3 cogs in one push (3 is max) the thumb lever doesn't retract itself back to the start position. I have to push it downward (as in toward the ground) to get it to flip back. Using the finger trigger to drop back down to a smaller cog also releases it -- but not as reliably, and of course then I need to shift back up a cog to where I wanted to be.

I tried a little light silicone lube in the lever hinge/center area, and have looked (from the outside) and can't see any obvious debris from manufacturing, but it's clearly hanging up when it shouldn't be. Doesn't seem to have any more out-of-rotation-plane play than any of the other 5 of these I've got in the stable on other bikes.

Anyone experienced this hang-up with rapidfires and have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Remember, if its a new new bike then will be under warranty.  Shifters should function, that's not unreasonable.

Comment: Sure, but it's a direct-sales bike and I know a fix or replacement here will be much simpler and faster. (If I just buy a new shifter and send them the receipt and explanation, they'll likely just credit me the $40 a new one costs.) However, I'd also rather get it working than toss it and replace.

Comment: I would be contacting the seller first, anything you do will possibly give them the wiggle to deny any claim.  Then maybe from there negotiate resolutions, weather that is reimbursement for a replacement or reimbursement for a visit to the local LBS or whatever.  I would never try fix some defect without first talking to the seller where warranty is concerned

Comment: So as to avoid piling on with "get a warranty replacement," comments let's maybe pretend this is a 5 year-old rapidfire that can use a fix?

Comment: Try disconnecting the shifter from the derailleur, and operating it with some light cable tension (lightly pull the free end). Same behavior then? Also, you may want to add your preference for a non-warranty solution to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it up on the stand to take a closer look. Turns out it was simpler than I thought -- nothing hanging up inside the shifter.

**The levers were interfering with each other. The top of the bottom lever was catching on the bottom of the top lever.**

That's why mashing them around would release them from each other.

The interference was only about 1mm or so, but enough to not only stop the retraction on the bottom, but to make shifts from the bottom sometimes hang up on the top on the way in -- and that had the effect of changing a full swing, 3-cog shift into a 2.

Ideas for fixing included bending them slightly apart (but how far is the metal inside the plastic? And can you bend it without wrecking the inside?). I hit the plastic with a heat gun to try and soften it to just bend that a little, but no go there -- seems to be a pretty dense resin that doesn't soften under the sort of heat that moves typical thermoplastics -- maybe even glass reinforced.

Idea 3 was simplest. I just sanded the areas that were interfering. Some 80 grit followed by fine emery cloth and they are clear enough to function properly. So, about 10 minutes work. Crummy pictures follow, showing the levers post sanding. They still brush each other slightly sometimes, but not enough to get caught.

[image: clearance during shifting passes]

[image: top of bottom lever]

[image: bottom of top lever]

Comment: This shifter, designed to be thin / low profile, may be more susceptible to this problem than others in Shimano's rapidfire line. I compared it to a couple more brand-new rapidfires that came on the wife & kid's bikes (also 10 speed) and those are bulkier shifters with the indicator top of bar rather than under, and they have MUCH more clearance between the levers. At least 3-4mm.

Answer (score 1):

Start with some further diagnosis - pull on the exposed inner cable anywhere it is accessible.  Confirm the problem is still in the shifter even with additional cable tension.

Then blast the whole shifter with solvent - seriously flood it while working the action.   WD-40 is acceptable for this purpose because its relatively cheap. 
Older shifters sometimes have their lubricant gum up which makes pivots work slower and need higher spring tension before operating.  Yes yours is a new bike but the shifter itself might be older.

I also wonder if the lever is subtly bent, in a way that is hanging up with the deeper 3-shift action.  Could also be a burr on a corner that is adding friction in a way that matches.  That you have to push the lever down hints something on top might be binding.   Needle files and thin strips of sandpaper might be helpful on corners.

Last resort is to start removing covers - the pawls and springs are finicky and likely to pop out, but removing the cover might show something.

Endgame, this is a $75NZ / $50USD / 50 Euro shifter.   If you break it, replacement is much cheaper than the expensive models, but it would still be annoying to do so.

Comment: Saw this after I fixed it! Subtle bend may have been it, though they looked straight. They were indeed interfering with each other out on the resin end. And you also nailed it on the sanding. I refrained from flooding it with lube b/c IME these often have some grease in various places that I'd rather not wash out with light lube.

Answer (score 1):

The thumb lever not retracting fully or consistently on a new Shimano flat bar shifter, but doing so when coaxed, is usually the same problem.

If you remove the lower cover of many models, you find the thumb lever has a simple adjusting hex nut to regulate its free play. Too loose and it has slop, too tight and the return spring force is insufficient to prevent binding (the problem you're having). That nut's adjustment is held by a plastic locking clip that slips over the wrench flats once the adjustment is made, hence giving a 1/6 turn (60 degree) adjustment interval.

Affected new models typically are tight by 1/6 of a turn. Probably they all break in eventually anyway; I've corrected this on a handful of new bikes, but it's not really seen in the wild. Carefully remove the lower cover and the clip, loosen the nut (CCW) a sixth of a turn, put the clip back on and test to see if the issue is gone.